# Strapi: customize fields in response

Tags: graphql, strapi, rest

Can anyone help with how to customise or remove some fields in the Strapi API response.
for eg. by default Strapi will include fields like:

> updated_by,
> created_by,
> createdAt,
> updatedAt,
> __v,
> _id,
> id

Sample Response JSON

```html
[{
    "_id": "5f5bcb3fc444444400000",
    "feature_name": "Latest News",
    "feature_shortcode": "latest",
    "feature_order": 12,
    "createdAt": "2020-09-11T19:08:47.576Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-11T19:08:47.715Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "created_by": {
      "_id": "5iasdf98a7dsf98a7s98fd",
      "username": null,
      "firstname": "xxxxx",
      "lastname": "xxxxxx",
      "createdAt": "2020-09-11T18:53:45.626Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-09-11T18:53:45.775Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "id": "lkajsfd98as9df8590e130f235c"
    },
    "updated_by": {
      "_id": "5f5bc7b9245b590e130f235c",
      "username": null,
      "firstname": "xxxxx",
      "lastname": "xxxxxxx",
      "createdAt": "2020-09-11T18:53:45.626Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-09-11T18:53:45.775Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "id": "5f5bc7bsdfasdf90e130f235c"
    },
    "id": "5fasdfhgthrth4f3e620f"
  }
  ]
```

How can I configure it to only show the fields that I have created in my collection? (feature_name, feature_shortcode, feature_order)

Comment: Use graphql: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/getting-started/graphql.html or custom controllers: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/custom-data-response.html#introduction